# How to open an html file in a given firefox profile?

Tags: firefox, browser, file-association, ubuntu-16.04, firefox-profile

I have installed multiple browsers. Firefox has multiple profiles. When I have an HTML file, if I select it and hit enter, the file is always opened in the default profile. Right Click and "open with" shows multiple browsers, but not multiple  profiles within the same browser.

How to choose which profile the file should open in (without changing the default profile)?

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With commandline:

```
firefox --profile <profile-name> <html-file>
```

You could add a custom option to your file manager to open it with the given command.

I don't know if nautilus could do this natively therefore I will give an example  with `.desktop` files.

Create an entry `~/.local/share/applications/firefox-second-profile.desktop` or you could copy the firefox desktop file from `usr/share/applications/` into it.
Find the `Exec=` location and change:

```
Exec=firefox --profile <profile-name> %U
```

**Edit:**

Found a more detailed explanation of adding an entry to nautilus via `.desktop` file. Use the upper firefox command and set your profile name. I recommend to copy the already existing firefox desktop file and only change the exec section and name. Through this you still have all benefits like icon and translations.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/317392/how-to-add-a-custom-program-to-open-with-list-of-programs-in-xubuntu-13-04-ho
- https://itsfoss.com/add-application-list-open-applications-ubuntu-1310/